# Dynamically generate angular directive within a loop

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to dynamically compile and append a directive with a dynamic attribute in the directive; however, I keep getting an error.

Anyone know why?

http://plnkr.co/edit/wOb9UuFwXR0dCZx2e2xg?p=preview

```
angular.module('plunker', [])

  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.foo = {
      bar: 'world'
    };
  }).directive('addEditConfig', AddEditConfig)

  .directive('inputElement', InputElement);


function AddEditConfig($compile) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            edit: '@',
            config: '=',
            display: '=',
            parentController: '='
        },
        template: '<div id="dynamicForm"></div>',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        controller: AddEditConfigController,
        link: linkFunction
    }

    return directive;

    function linkFunction(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        var params = [{description: 'foo', value:'bar'}, {description: 'foo', value:'bar'}, {description: 'foo', value:'bar'}, {description: 'foo', value:'bar'}];
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            angular.element(document.getElementById('dynamicForm')).append($compile('<input-element param="' + params[i] + '"></input-element>')(scope));
        }
    }
};

function AddEditConfigController() {
};

function InputElement() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            param: '='
        },
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        template: '<div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-8"> <input id="port" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="{{vm.param.description}}" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="vm.param.value"/> </div></div>',
        controller: InputElementController,
        link: linkFunction
    }
    return directive;

    function linkFunction(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
    }
};

function InputElementController() {
    var vm = this;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem (at least one of them) is in this statement :

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('dynamicForm')).append($compile('<input-element param="' + params[i] + '"></input-element>')(scope));
```

Writing this `param="' + params[i] + '"` generates the following DOM `param="[Object Object]"`.
So It will never work as expected.

One way to achieve this :

```
angular.module('plunker', [])

  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.foo = {
      bar: 'world'
    };
  }).directive('addEditConfig', AddEditConfig)

  .directive('inputElement', InputElement);


function AddEditConfig($compile) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            edit: '@',
            config: '=',
            display: '=',
            parentController: '='
        },
        template: '<div id="dynamicForm"><input-element param="param" ng-repeat="param in vm.params"></input-element></div>',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        controller: AddEditConfigController
    }
    return directive;
};

function AddEditConfigController() {
  this.params = [{description: 'foo', value:'bar'}, {description: 'foo1', value:'bar1'}, {description: 'foo2', value:'bar2'}, {description: 'foo3', value:''}];
};

function InputElement() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            param: '='
        },
        template: '<div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-8"> <input id="port" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="{{param.description}}" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="param.value"/> </div></div>'
    }
    return directive;

};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/KdPvJdBsRwbjNsBCIvVh?p=preview

Comment: I think i might have gotten it figured out: http://plnkr.co/edit/m6zL2ziidu9NnWZpiHOO?p=preview

Which way do you think would be considered "best practice"? I don't really like ng-repeats as I can't debug 'em. :(

Comment: `$compile('<input-element param="params[' + i + ']"></input-element>')` is a good one. I just think `ng-repeat` makes your code easier to read and does the same kind of implementation. So why reinventing the wheel? By the way : this SO question proves your implementation is not easier to debug, huh ? ;)

Comment: If you do know of a way to debug html logic I'd honestly love to learn about it. :)